# How can i add an image to a blank activity in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable

I hope you are well.

Firstly, apologies if this appears to be a stupid question however can somebody explain how on earth I can add an image to a blank activity in android studio?

I am using API version 19 and have created a blank activity in a new project. I have an image I would like to use in PNG format, it has a transparent background.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: that is what i had tried, but it doesn't let me browse for a image?

Comment: Set the background of your root view to the image or add an ImageView to the root and use your image in that.

Comment: Then you need to post the code you have and explain the problem. You also need to make sure you have the image in your `drawable` folders

Comment: okay, i think i know what i am doing, say my image is called blackbox.png, would i need to copy that into drawable-hdpi/, drawable-mdpi/ and so on?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_swoosh_image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You may want to use LinearLayout or FrameLayout depending on what else you want to show.

Comment: *"You may want to use LinearLayout or FrameLayout"* why just those two?

Answer (score 1):

1) Use an ImageView which can be accessed at the design tab,

2) Paste the Image  (say"xyz.png") to the drawable folder of your project

3) later in the attribute section of the ImageView , in the src atribute as "@drawable/xyz.png"

4) All the best ! Hope it was helpful.